# search and remove a node from linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am using a linked list without using collections class for data structure practice.
I wanted to remove an element from the linked list after passing the element value to function

This is the function that i've written.

```
public boolean remove(String s)
    {
        if(head.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        {
            head = head.getNext();
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            Node p =head;
            Node current=p.getNext();

            while(true) {
                if(current == null || current.getName().equals(s)) {
                    break;
                }
                p = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            if (current == null)
            {
                p.setNext(current.getNext());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i'm using Node p to store the previous node and current node.

The code falls in the return false section and there is no change in the list.Also i'm getting a null pointer exception warning in the *p.setNext(**current**.getNext())* here.

Please let me know where i'm making mistake.

Comment: if (current == null) should be if (current!= null)

Comment: thank you all .....was such a silly mistake.

Comment: Have you managed to implement the list ? More help needed ?

Comment: yes, it was just a silly mistake on my part. List works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the Null Pointer Exception this should ring a bell

```
if (current == null)
{
    p.setNext(current.getNext());
    return true;
}
```

**current** is null and you are trying to invoke a method from it.

Also it doesn't seem you handle the corner cases like the list is empty or having one element.

Answer (score 1):

```
current == null
```

is the not found case. When `current == null` we should return false, and calling `current.getNext()` will give the null pointer error. Similarly, the found case is not getting into the block you want. It should suffice, I think, to say `if (current != null)` where you have `if (current == null)`

I found https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/ helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking true condition based on current value which possibly may or may not be null, you should be having one boolean flag.
This flag value can be made true if you find the passed element.

```
while(true) {
                if(current == null || current.getName().equals(s)) {
                flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                p = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            if (flag)
            { 
            if(current!=null)
                p.setNext(current.getNext());
            return true;
            }
```